# Heroku or GAE better for the deployment of my application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, heroku, deployment, libraries

Im new in web programming and python and i ve been building a web application for basic network analysis.

My app is running locally so far with flask microframework, but i want to check which platform is the best about my app's deployment.

The problem is that the implemetantion of my application requires a lot of libraries, such as numpy, matplotlib, networkx and im getting trouble of installing all theses libraries on my virtualvenv environemnt with pip as well as heroku's failure to install all of these for example.

So, my question is, which platform supports all these libraries and its more suitable for my application's requirments?

Comment: this might help.  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

Comment: so, as far as i can get, it doesn't support networkx, does it?

Comment: supports most pure python modules, lots of other stuff too. Just start a project, include what you need in it with some test cases then deploy it. If it works (the tests pass), you are on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27 for list of libraries that come with Google App Engine. You can include any other libraries with your project as long as they are Python-only code, i.e. no compiled C-libraries.